# facebook sdk 3.18.1 in android

Tags: android, facebook

I use the facebook SDK 3.18.1 in my android app and i have some problems with minimum SDK version. In my app the gradle.xml file contains

```
`compileSdkVersion 20
 buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19`
```

and in dependencies defined

```
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
 compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
 compile files('./libs/bolts.jar')
 compile project(':facebook')`
```

The gradle.properties file contains

```
`ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=20`
```

The build.gradle of facebook is

```
`apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}`
```

When i rebuild i take this message: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library projectName:facebook:unspecified

Comment: Could you post the gradle of the facebook?

Comment: Yes of course, i have added in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to run the app with below changes:

In gradle.properties file:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=11
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=11
```

In build.gradle of project:

```
 compileSdkVersion 20
 buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is Android L Preview cannot target previous Android version and in the facebook SDK,
the gradle getting the value from the project gradle so it will set the minimum SDK and target SDK to API 19 (KitKat)

So change to this one

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
```

**EDIT**

Looks like you set the target version to 20 (Android L) accidentally.
so change this one

gradle.xml

```
compileSdkVersion 15
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
```

gradle.properties

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=15
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=15
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=15
```

Comment: I have tried. I haven't build errors but i take this message Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: What device that you tried install to? is it Android L device or not? and is there any special reason why are you targeting Android L Preview?

Comment: The device is Samsung Galaxy-Young the model: GT-S6310. I don't know about Android L.

Comment: Android Version 4.1.2

Comment: Again I take the same message: [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62231/discussion-between-nayoso-and-user3607469).